# A systematic way to construct higher order methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am in numerical methods and my professor introduced how one may construct a higher order method for multi-step methods for $y'(x) = f(x,y(x))$ in the form:

$\sum_{s=0}^{k}\alpha_s y_{n+s} = h\sum_{s=0}^{k}\beta_s f(x_{n+s}, y_{n+s})$

As:

1. We look at the local truncation error $(T_h)_n = \frac{1}{h}\sum\alpha_s y_{n+s}-\sum_{s=0}^{k}\beta_s f(x_{n+s}, y_{n+s})$
2. Define the linear map $(L_h y)_n = \frac{1}{h}\sum\alpha_s y(x+sh)-\sum_{s=0}^{k}\beta_s y'(x+sh)$
3. Find $\alpha$'s and $\beta$'s such that $(L_h y)_n = 0$ for $y$ a polynomial.

Can someone give me a specific example (or reference to a written out example) of how you would do this?  Thank you, in advance, for your time and help.

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3473300/ I gave an algorithm to compute coefficients for Adams-Bashford-Moulton of any order. For BDF a similar mechanism exists.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358496/numerical-method-forward-finite-difference-coefficient is for forward difference quotients, BDF has reversed coefficient sequences with alternating signs. The general approach with the Taylor shift operator generalizes the usual manipulations of order conditions.

Comment: Thank you, Lutz!